# What is the significance of subscription status list option in pubsub model of MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

How is the subscription list option different from the subscription status list option in IBM MQ?
When do we use the subscription list status option?

Comment: Are you asking about the MQSC command "DISPLAY SUB" vs "DISPLAY SBSTATUS"?

Answer (score 0):

The subscription list displays the *configuration* of the subscriptions
The subscription list status display the current *status* of the subscriptions